# Data access layer in Python

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and still learning and trying to explore new things every day. I came from a C# background where we used to have a different data access layer with classes named as table and queries written in that later that can be accessed in business layer.

I want to achieve the same functionality in Python. From my module, I do not want to write the same query twice. I want to keep the queries in a different module and let everyone use that module rather than having their own version of the query in every module.

Is there a good article anyone can suggest me to look at? Has anyone done this kind of data manipulation with Python? Like reading, inserting and updating with some common module in a data access layer.

Comment: if you are making a web app or api, Django is a very common and popular MVC framework that will help manage the various components of your app and eliminate much of the boilerplate logic of something more custom: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jumping past your simple question about constructing Data Access Objects and utilizing those objects in other modules...

I would suggest you familiarize yourself with [ORMs (Object Relational Mappers)](https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html). Some examples of popular ORMs for Python are [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/).

Another helpful link might be this [reddit thread, which discusses going from writing Java code to writing Python](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/es7g7/diving_in_to_python_from_java_what_should_i_know/), which is a slight shift in thinking (but not by much: although, there is definitely a "Java" way of doing things and a "Python" way of doing things).

Coming back to the DAO concept, that is definitely something you can do in Python. Especially, because what you are hinting at would help with code reuse:

> I want to keep the queries in a different module and let everyone use that module rather than having their own version of query in every module.

That is definitely consistent with good design practices, however, people will have different opinions on how this should be done (in Python).